# HTML / JavaScript multiple choice quiz: setting header and answer choices functions

Tags: javascript, html, function, object, innerhtml

I'm trying to understand this multiple choice JavaScript quiz and I'm stuck on the following functions:

```
function setHeader(questionNum) {
    var questionHeaderEl = document.getElementById("questionHeader");
    questionHeaderEl.innerHTML = allQuestions[questionNum].question;
}

function setAnswer(idEl, questionNum, choiceNum) {
    var choiceEl = document.getElementById(idEl);
    choiceEl.innerHTML = allQuestions[questionNum].choices[choiceNum];
}
```

I know that the setHeader function displays the question string from the object literal array, but I don't fully get the mechanics of either function. Could someone please explain what exactly is going on?

See the quiz code in full: http://jsfiddle.net/alxers/v9t4t/

Answer (score 0):

The setHeader function gets the header element for displaying the question by its id attribute, "questionHeader". Then it sets the inner html (innerHTML) to the value in the object retrieved from the array "allQuestions".

For the setAnswer function, it gets the label and sets its inner html to value found in the "choiceNum"-th index of the choice property of the "questionNum"-th  index of the "allQuestions" array.